# Como actualizar una celda en datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

¿Cómo podria actualizar una celda en especifico?

Tengo unos campos en la cual los lleno y los agrego con ese boton a una tabla en la parte de abajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como observan los 3 campos son **input**. La lógica es la siguiente: Yo lleno los campos arriba, y luego se agrega la fila, pero si quisiera volver a ingresar el codigo de ese producto ya registrado y que yo quisiera cambiar la **CANTIDAD** ya no quiero que sea **20** sino **10** ¿cómo lo hago para pasar el nuevo valor ingresado en la parte de arriba y que se reemplaze en el de abajo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="card-body p-1 row g-1">
  <input id="txtIdProducto" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="input-group mb-0 ">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onclick="productoLimpiar()"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
      <input type="text" id="txtCodigo" class="form-control" onfocusout="productoBuscarManual()" placeholder="CODIGO O SKU" aria-describedby="button-addon1" autocomplete="off" style="font-size: 12px;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="productoBuscar()"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <input type="text" id="txtDescripcion" style="font-size: 12px;" class="form-control full-width" disabled="disabled" placeholder="DESCRIPCION">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" id="txtCostoActual" style="font-size: 12px;" class="form-control text-center floatNumberField" placeholder="0.000000">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" id="txtDescuento" style="font-size: 12px;" class="form-control text-center floatNumberField" placeholder="0.000000">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <div class="input-group mb-0 ">
      <input type="number" id="txtCantidad" style="font-size: 12px;" class=" form-control full-width text-lg-center" placeholder="0" min="1" max="500000" autocomplete="off">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="AñadirRegistro" onclick="ProductoGuardar()"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
{
  "data": "ProductoCantidad",
  render: function(data, type, row) {
    return '<input type="text" id="tableCantidad" style="font-size: 12px;"  class=" form-control full-width text-lg-center" value="' + parseFloat(data).toFixed(0) + '" >';
  }
},
```

El código de arriba es el **input** que esta dentro de la tabla.

En el boton `+` tengo la siguiente función:

```
function ProductoGuardar() {
  var Bodega = {
    ProductoFila: $("#txtIdProducto").val(),
    ProductoCodigo: $("#txtCodigo").val(),
    ProductoNombre: $("#txtDescripcion").val(),
    ProductoCostoActual: $("#txtCostoActual").val(),
    ProductoCantidad: $("#txtCantidad").val(),
    Descuento: $("#txtDescuento").val(),
    ProductoTotal: $("#txtCostoActual").val() * $("#txtCantidad").val() - $("#txtDescuento").val(),
  }
```

Esa función la llamo desde mi boton con un **onclick** y esto es lo que armé a base de ejemplos, pero no funciona nada en absoluto.

```
$('#AñadirRegistro').on('click', function() {
  $("#tableCantidad").val("#txtCantidad");

  var UpdateTD = $("#tableCantidad").parent('td');
  tabladata.cell(UpdateTD).data(UpdateTD.val()).draw();
});
```

Comment: yo no veo c# por ningun lado aca....

Comment: Lo normal es poner un nuevo icono de **editar** en el nuevo registro, quizás al lado de la papelera estaría bien, y alli aplicar el código para editarlo... ¿que ocurre si has pulsado el boton + varias veces y quieres editar solo uno de ellos de esta forma que propones?  No parece demasiado lógico así como lo planteas

Comment: @masterguru creo que lo explique mal... 1)Arriba tengo 5 input donde yo hare un registro nuevo. Ese registro lo busco en un modal y luego me pasa los datos de ID Y DESCRIPCION y me los llena en los primeros 2 input luego los otros 3 tengo que llenarlos yo. Al momento de completarlos y le doy al boton + se añaden 2) Lo que quisera es que al momento de buscar de nuevo el mismo codigo no me tire error que el registro ya existe si no que unicamente sume los datos de CANTIDAD con los que ya se habian registrado... a modo de no hacer 2 lineas similares con el mismo ID

Comment: Por lo que veo es un datatable, y desconozco como funciona su actualización. Por otra parte, en la pregunta deberias poner siempre el HTML al cual te refieres, y tambien como creas el datatable con javascript, para que podamos reproducir tu ejemplo en nuestros dispositivos y ayudarte mejor sin tener que esforzarnos en escribirlo de 0 nosotros, y así obtendrás mejores ayudas.  Léete lo del [example] para entender mejor lo que te pido, que aunque te suponga un esfuerzo adicional, muchas veces, tan solo por tener que hacerlo, tu mismo acabas encontrando la respuesta.

Comment: @masterguru ya añadi el codigo html

Comment: Sigue faltando algo de código pero bueno, ahora se entiende mejor. Según parece, siempre estás añadiendo los mismos **id** en cada fila para los **input**, cosa que ya está mal si luego necesitas hacer cualquier cosa con ellos, pues solo te va a coger el primero de ellos. Si vas a usar **id** éstos deben ser **únicos** siempre.

Comment: Dicho esto, sigo sin saber como modificar la celda de un datatable, supongo que en su documentación lo deben explicar, pero independientemente de eso, lo que veo claro es que esto esta mal: `$("#tableCantidad").val("#txtCantidad");` pues debería ser algo asi: `$("#tableCantidad").val($("#txtCantidad").val());` para que cogiera el value de `#txtCantidad` correctamente.  Aún así, dudo que eso te arregle nada, pues si tienes varias filas con el mismo **id** solo se cambiará el primero de ellos, y eso no creo que actualice el resto de campos de la fila en un datatable.